# Reset Arduino by connecting vcc and gnd?

Tags: digispark

A follow up question on my previous question, if a memory card reader can be used with three pins (digispark Attiny 85):

[Can I read from a memory card with three pins?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70590/can-i-read-from-a-memory-card-with-three-pins)

Now I came up with another idea.
Since the USB connector or the VCC pin can power an Arduino my guess is that they are in parallel and the actual Arduino is connected to both.
Kind of like this very bad schematic made on my phone: (sorry for that)
[image]
Where the blue stuff is the Arduino chip.

If that is true then adding the push button between VCC and GND with a resistor between should remove the power of the Arduino?
In that case I can have my code in setup() and use the pus button to reset the Arduino, and still have four pins to the memory card reader.

Or is this wrong? What kind of resistor value do I need to make sure I don't short the USB connector but still have less resistance than the Arduino chip?

Comment: What's the problem with pulling the RST line down to GND? Shorting a supply is likely to kill it dead (or in the worst case blow it up and cause a fire).

Comment: @Dougie as far as I can see it doesn't have a reset pin

Comment: Then it ain't an Arduino. They even have a button on the board to ground the RST pin

Comment: @Dougie as i wrote in the question, it's a digispark Attiny 85. It doesn't have a reset button, and not even a dedicated reset pin. It's a pin that I need to use to the SD card reader

Comment: Yes it does pin#1 on the chip is the RST line. So can you change the description as it is NOT an Arduino.

Comment: It's quite common to use the name Arduino as board platform name, just like these does https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/242 . What is your point really? The question clearly state what device it is. Just as if I would ask a question about a pro mini vs mega, the pin layout and the count of pins is clearly different. No I can't use pin 1, as I wrote I need all the pins for a SD card reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is wrong. That is very, very wrong. That is one of the worst things you can do to a USB connection short of plugging it into the mains.

Do not even consider doing this.  Short circuits are never a good idea.

Comment: Not even with a resistor?

Comment: Not even with a resistor. To make it "reset" you'd be having to cause the voltage to drop below the brownout threshold of the MCU. The only way that will happen is if you draw more current than the supply can give you. A good USB host will shut off the power to a port where that happens and alert you that it has a malfunctioning device. A bad one will just melt.

Comment: It's a good thing I asked then.. :-)